# c program to find the least number of swaps to arrange an 3x3 array of 1-9 in ascending order under conditions on swaps

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

PS- i don't have a lot of programming experience, i am new to all this. so please help me solve this problem which i got as a project in college.

conditions of the game : you may swap two adjacent tiles if their sum is a prime number. Two tiles are considered adjacent if they have a common edge.

this is a problem from
http://www.codechef.com/problems/H1

though solutions are available there, but i am not able to understand them.

i have been working on this for a long this but i am not able to solve this.

the first program i made swaps any two tiles (which follow conditions) randomly. this way it calculates the swaps. for easy problems, it will most probably find the least number of counts. but for complex ones it hardly does. it is not at all efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int a[]={1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int b[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int c[9];
int count=0;

void swap(){
    int p,q,tmp;
for(p=0;p<9;p++){
    for(q=p+1;q<9;q++){
            if(prime(a[p],a[q])&&position(p,q)){
    if(a[p]>a[q]){
        tmp=a[p];
        a[p]=a[q];
        a[q]=tmp;
        count++;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    printf("\n\nswapstart\n\n");
    for(p=0;p<9;p++){
        printf("%d ", a[p]);
    }
    printf("\n\nswapover\n\n");
}

int prime(int a, int b){
int c=a+b;
if(c==3||c==5||c==7||c==11||c==13||c==17){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

int position(int a, int b){
if((a-b==1||b-a==1||a-b==3||b-a==3) && (!((a==2&&b==3)||(a==3&&b==2)||(a==5&&b==6)||(a==6&&b==5))))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,temp,cnd=0,m,times=1000,finalcount=10000000;

    srand(time(NULL));

   for(m=0;m<9;m++){
            c[m]=a[m];
        }
while(times--){

   for(m=0;m<9;m++){
            if(a[m]==b[m]){
               cnd=1;
               }
                else{
                    cnd=0;
                    break;
                }
        }
   while(cnd==0){

    i=rand()%9;
    j=rand()%9;

    if(prime(a[i],a[j])&&position(i,j)){
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;
        count++;

        for(m=0;m<9;m++){
            if(a[m]==b[m]){
               cnd=1;
               }
                else{
                    cnd=0;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
   }

for(m=0;m<9;m++){
    printf("%d ", a[m]);
    a[m]=c[m];
}
if(count<finalcount){
    finalcount=count;
}
printf("remaining = %d count= %d, finalcount= %d\n", times, count, finalcount);
count=0;
cnd=0;
}
    return 0;
}
```

secondly i made another program. it targets the least number first i.e. 1, then it tries to bring it to the 0th position. if it fails to do so, then it goes to 2. and so on. it also is somehow able to solve basic problems (tough not in minimum ways) but not the more complex ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a[]={2,6,3,1,4,5,7,9,8},b[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},c[9];

int i,j,m,trgt=1,temp,cnt=0;

int prime(int a, int b){
int c=a+b;
if(c==3||c==5||c==7||c==11||c==13||c==17){
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

int position(int a, int b){
if((a-b==1||b-a==1||a-b==3||b-a==3) && (!((a==2&&b==3)||(a==3&&b==2)||(a==5&&b==6)||(a==6&&b==5))))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

int condition(){
for(m=0;m<9;m++){
    if(a[m]==b[m]);
    else
        return 1;
}
return 0;
}

int cond(){
    if(a[trgt-1]==trgt)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int block(){
    int p;
for(p=0;p<9;p++){
    if(a[p]==c[p]);
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}

void target(int t){
    for(m=0;m<9;m++){
        c[m]=a[m];
        printf("%d ", a[m]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(cond()){

    j=rand()%9;
if(prime(a[t],a[j])&&position(t,j)){
    temp=a[t];
    a[t]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    t=j;
    cnt++;
}
if(block()){
    break;
}
}
}

int main()
{
            while(condition()){
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(a[i]==trgt){
            target(i);
        trgt++;
        }
    }
    trgt=1;
    }
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is quite small - only 9 elements. This means its states are no more than 9! = 362880 (in fact not all of the 9! are possible but you can ignore this). Imagine you have a graph and you need to find the minimal number of edges that take you from a given vertex(the start position) to another vertex(the end position or the sorted array). Now problem seems easier, right? A simple [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and you are done! Now to solve the problem you don't have to actually build the graph - the representation you are given is enough. Make the vertices of your graph be represented by arrays and the edges are the possible swaps you can perform on the given array.

Comment: i made another program to find the minimum number of flips required to solve the puzzle following your suggestions. it works fine for minimum number flips under 7, but for more than that, it does not work. here is the link to the new program http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044474/program-to-sort-an-array-under-conditions-on-sum-and-movement-of-elements/23047551?noredirect=1#23047551