# Program to sort an array under conditions on sum and movement of elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

> You are given a 3x3 array of numbers from 1-9.
>   At each step, you may swap two adjacent tiles if their sum is a prime number. Two tiles are considered adjacent if they have a common edge.

This is a problem from:
http://www.codechef.com/problems/H1

I made this program which sorts the given array following the given rules. For arrays/puzzles with number of minimum flips=7, it works. but for arrays/puzzles with minimum flips more than that it does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int a[9]={6,3,5,4,7,2,1,9,8};
//6,3,5,7,9,4,1,8,2
int b[9]={0};
int c[9]={0};
int d[9]={0};
int e[9]={0};
int sortcond=0,count=0;
typedef struct Queue
{
        int capacity;
        int size;
        int front;
        int rear;
        int *elements;
}Queue;

Queue * createQueue(int maxElements)
{
        Queue *Q;
        Q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        Q->elements = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxElements);
        Q->size = 0;
        Q->capacity = maxElements;
        Q->front = 0;
        Q->rear = -1;
        return Q;
}
void Dequeue(Queue *Q)
{
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            Q->size--;
                Q->front++;
                if(Q->front==Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->front=0;
                }
        }
        return;
}
int front(Queue *Q)
{
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        return Q->elements[Q->front];
}


void Enqueue(Queue *Q,int element)
{
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
        {
               printf("Queue is Full\n");
        }
        else
        {
                Q->size++;
                Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->rear = 0;
                }
                    Q->elements[Q->rear] = element;
        }
        return;
}

void enqueue(Queue *Q,int *element)
{
    int i;
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
        {
                printf("Queue is Full\n");
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<9;i++){
                Q->size++;
                Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->rear = 0;
                }
                    Q->elements[Q->rear] = *(element+i);

                    }
        }
        return;
}

void EnQueue(Queue *Q,int *element)
{

    int i;
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
        {
                printf("Queue is Full\n");
        }
        else
        {
             Q->elements[Q->rear] = *element;

            for(i=1;i<9;i++){
                Q->size++;
                Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->rear = 0;
                }
                    Q->elements[Q->rear] = *(element+i);

                    }
        }
        return;
}

Queue *que,*seen;

int primecheck(int num1,int num2){
    switch(num1+num2){
        case  3:
        case  5:
        case  7:
        case 11:
        case 13:
        case 17:
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int possibleflips(){
int validpair[12][2] = { {0,1}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {6,7}, {7,8}, {0,3}, {3,6}, {1,4}, {4,7}, {2,5}, {5,8} };
int i,j,p,q,temp,seencond,seencond2;
//printf("entered possibleflips\n");
for(i=0;i<12;i++){
    int p = validpair[i][0];
    int q = validpair[i][1];
    if(primecheck(b[p],b[q])){
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            c[j]=b[j];
        }
        temp=c[p];
        c[p]=c[q];
        c[q]=temp;
        while(front(seen)!=0){
        seencond=1;
        seencond2=0;
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            d[j]=front(seen);
           if(c[j]==front(seen));
           else
            seencond=0;
           Dequeue(seen);
        }
        enqueue(seen,d);
        if(seencond==1){
            seencond2=1;
        }
        }
        if(seencond2==0){
            EnQueue(seen,c);
            Enqueue(seen,0);
            enqueue(que,c);
        }
        else{
            Dequeue(seen);
            Enqueue(seen,0);
        }
    }
}
//printf("exit possibleflips\n");
return;
}

int searching(){
    int  i,cond;
    //printf("entered search\n");
while(front(que)!=0){
        cond=1;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            e[i]=front(que);
        if(front(que)==i+1);
        else
            cond=0;
        Dequeue(que);
    }
    enqueue(que,e);
    if(cond==1){
        sortcond=1;
        return;
    }
}
Dequeue(que);
Enqueue(que,0);
//printf("exit search\n");
return;
}

int firststep(){
int i;
//printf("firststep\n");
while(sortcond==0){
    while(front(que)!=0){
            for(i=0;i<9;i++){
                b[i]=front(que);
                //printf("%d ",b[i]);
                Dequeue(que);
            }
            //printf("\n");
    possibleflips();
}
Dequeue(que);
Enqueue(que,0);
searching();
count++;
}
return;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    que=createQueue(5000000);
    seen=createQueue(5000000);
    enqueue(que,a);
    Enqueue(que,0);
    enqueue(seen,a);
    Enqueue(seen,0);
    firststep();
    printf("count %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

a[] is the given array (you can put some simple problem like 1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9) and it works for them.

it first adds the given array to queue and, finds the arrays you can make in one swap on the given array and adds them to queue and removes the given array from the queue. searches if any of them makes it 1,2..9. If not, then it finds the arrays you can make in one more swap, i.e. two swaps away from the given array, and adds them to queue and so on. It also checks for the repetition of cases.

Works fine for arrays with minimum number of flips under 7 e.g. {6,3,5,7,9,4,1,8,2}. but for arrays with minimum number of flips more than that, e.g. {6,3,5,4,7,2,1,9,8}, it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps `malloc` is failing to allocate that large chunk; check results of `malloc` for `NULL`. Also, the `Enqueue` function may result in `size > capacity` which will screw everything up.

Comment: yeah, maybe, but it is not displaying anything like "queue is full", which it is supposed to display in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't go through the whole code you gave, but as far as I could understand it, you don't check partial results for uniqueness: you never know if the board state has already been checked. As a result your code makes the same flips to and fro, repeating the same analysis multiple times. The same board states are enqueued again and again, resulting in data structure overflow.

Add another queue, eg. `Queue *seen;`, to keep all numbers' permutations tested, and check every new permuttion in `posflips()` if it is already in `seen`. If so, ignore the permutation, else add it both to `qu` and to `seen`.

PS.
You know the numbers are 1 to 9 only, so the sum of two can be 3 to 17, consequently there are only 6 possible primes and your `primecheck()` can be simplified to

```
int primecheck(int numloc1,int numloc2){
    switch(numloc1+numloc2){
        case  3:
        case  5:
        case  7:
        case 11:
        case 13:
        case 17:
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are 36 total pairs of tiles in your board and only 12 of them are pairs of adjacent tiles. So 2/3 of `primecheck()` invocations done in `posflips()` are useless. You should call `check()` first and only if it succeedes call `primecheck()`, like this:

```
if(check(i,j) && primecheck(c[i],c[j])){
    //....
}
```

In addidtion, you can get rid of `check()` at all. Your board is quite small, so it might be easier to enumerate all valid pairs of positions than test every pair for validity:

```
int validPair[12][2] = {
    {0,1}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {6,7}, {7,8},
    {0,3}, {3,6}, {1,4}, {4,7}, {2,5}, {5,8}
};
int p;
for(p=0;p<12;p++){
    int i = validPair[p][0];
    int j = validPair[p][1];
    if(primecheck(c[i],c[j])){
        // ... do flips
        // ... check flipped board against 'seen' queue
        // ... and Enqueue if the board not seen before
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you rename `seencond` to `arraysAreEqual` and `seencond2` to `arrayWasSeen` it will become quite obvious the initialization

```
arrayWasSeen=0;
```

formerly

```
seencond2=0;
```

should go just *before* the `while` loop.

Note: as you construct a flipped array in a separate place, you don't need `temp` variable – just cross-copy the two items from the original array:

```
for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    c[j]=b[j];
c[p]=b[q];
c[q]=b[p];
```

Comment: i added your suggestions to the program. it is working for minimum flips<=7, but for minimum flips more than that, it isn't working.

Comment: What does it mean 'it isn't working'? Does it fall into some loop and sits there forever...? Does it crash with some system exception...? Does it run out of memory...? Does it exhaust a given max queue length...? Does it print a wrong result...?

Comment: maybe falls into a loop and sits there forever. but this does not happen for minimum flips<=7

Comment: Did you try to add some prints to see how your queues grow and shrink, how many flips are done at each iteration, how many different array configurations were tested...? Did you try to run the program in a debugger and break it after some time, to see where it is stuck...?

Comment: there were some mistakes in the program. i was not properly implementing the dequeue and enqueue. tough its quite slow, but, now its working.